# Django table partitioning (split by attribute)

Tags: mysql, django, partitioning, database-partitioning

I've got a table of approx. 3 M rows. I'm aware it's not terribly big, but tle size has some performance impact. I already added several indexes, to improve search performance, but the commits take more than 0.3-0.5s.

The model defines a boolean attribute "active". Most of the commits are done on objects with "active = True" thus it would be great to split the table into two separate ones by this attribute.

Is there an easy way of accomplishing this in Django with MySQL database?

Comment: Have you tried to optimize the database settings?

Comment: Yes, I increased key buffer to 2.7GB and remounted drive with barrier = 0 setting, along with some other tweaks. Please suggest if you think there is something else that could help.

Comment: Please provide the SELECT statement and SHOW CREATE TABLE for the table(s) involved.  Only then can we help you optimize it.